# Unable to iterate thru list in autocomplete using up and down arrow key in dojo

Tags: css, autocomplete, dojo

Need help..Unable to iterate thru auto suggestions using up and down arrow keys on keyboard here is little code snippet

```
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
dojo.ready(function () {
    var div = dojo.query("#list-of-items");
    console.log(dojo.byId("search").getBoundingClientRect());
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId("search"), "onkeyup", function (evt) {
        if (dojo.byId("search").value.trim() === "") {
            dojo.forEach(div.query("li"), function (elm, i) {
                dojo.style(elm, {
                    "display": "block"
                });
            });
            dojo.style(dojo.query("#list-of-items")[0], {
                "display": "none"
            });

            if(evt.keyCode == 40){
                return;               
            }else if(evt.keyCode == 38){
                return;
            }
        } else {
            dojo.style(dojo.query("#list-of-items")[0], {
                "display": "inline-block"
            });
        }
        searchTable(this.value, evt);
    });

    function searchTable(inputVal, e) {
        console.log(inputVal);
        var list = dojo.query('#list-of-items');
        dojo.forEach(list.query('li'), function (elm, i) {
            var found = false;
            var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
            if (regExp.test(elm.innerText)) {
                found = true;
                if(i===0){
                    dojo.attr(elm, { className: "hlight" });
                }
                dojo.style(elm, {
                    "display": "block"
                });
                return false;
            }
            if (found == true) {
                dojo.style(elm, {
                    "display": "block"
                });

            } else {
                dojo.style(elm, {
                    "display": "none"
                });
            }
        });
    }

});
```

and also highlight auto suggest using this css class

```
.hlight{
    background:#faae00;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Please see working  **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mx9eQ/9/)**

**Thanks**

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not working with one of the widgets of Dojo like the `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` or `dijit/form/ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to keep an index that contains the highlighted value, then increment/decrease that index every time the up/down arrow is pressed.

You will also have to send that index with your `searchTable()` function so that it can add the `.hlight` class to the correct elements.

The hardest part is to correct that index when someone uses the up arrow when you're already on the first element (or the down arrow when you're on the last arrow). I solved that by adding a class `.visible` to the elements that are visible (in stead of just adding `display: block` or `display: none`), this way you can easily query all items that are visible.

I rewrote your code a bit, ending up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mx9eQ/10/). But still, my original question is still left, why don't you use the `dijit/form/ComboBox` or `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`? Dojo already has widgets that do this for you, you don't have to reinvent the wheel here (because it probably won't be as good).

Comment: I just wanted to implement custom autocomplete without relying on existing widgets

Comment: it still doesn't work properly..seen couple of issues in you fiddle

Comment: But are the up/down arrows doing something? In my browser the highlighted text is moving up/down.

Comment: yes it's moving but highlighted item remains highlighted and another item is highlighted when i move up and down

Comment: I think I explained pretty much how it should work and it works in my browser (Google Chrome v32). Now it's up to you to improve it and ask further questions if you did that.

Comment: Which browser are you using by the way? Because I find it quite strange since it's a simple `if` `else` structure that enables/disables the highlighted term (so theoretically there can only be one highlighted item).

Comment: not errors here's the scenario type 9 you get some options then remove 9 then type 3 you get some options.Now, you can see previous searched item was still highlighted

Comment: Solved it, the `display: block` was showing items that should be hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/mx9eQ/11/